# Why is Ubuntu configuring multiple ZRAM devices for swap

Tags: kernel, swap, zram

I plan to use zram as a device for swap.

The `init-zram-swapping` script delivered with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic in package `zram-config` is creating one zram device for each CPU.
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/zram-config

The package is unchanged up to *eoan*.

Why is this being done? Is there any advantage of having multiple zram devices configured for swap?

I could imagine that it would help to not block on compression when working with the swap, but since kernel 4.7 it will always have multiple compression streams. One per online CPU.
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/43209ea2d17aae1540d4e28274e36404f72702f2

Even for older kernels I would have expected to see the `max_comp_streams` attribute being used and having one zram device.

So was the script just not adjusted with newer kernel versions available or is there another benefit of having multiple zram devices?

Answer (score 0):

When pagging occurs in a memory owned by a given CPU (especially in a NUMA configuration - imagine current EPYC processors with their 8-channel memory controllers and NUMA nodes) it's most effective to not copy this memory over to another CPU's memory (and disturb it's threads).  So I bet it's for performance reasons.

Comment: I understand the argument regarding locality. But for that reason zram already creates a worker for each online CPU, which would include individual workers on each NUMA node. So why having multiple swap devices? For NUMA it would be nice to run the swapping code on a CPU with fast memory access. It sounds unlikely that the pages selecting for swapping are in the local cache on the CPU, so I would expect memory access in any case. The code gives no indication regarding NUMA, so I have doubts that it is related to this.